# Convert 1 second delay in 200,000KM to delay in 825 miles?

Tags: time

I would like to know the delay in 825 miles of fiber if there is 1 second of delay in 200,000KM of fiber without counting for re-gen sites?

Comment: You need help with basic arithmetic? Just pop into the nearest primary school and ask one of the kids.

Answer (score 3):

You can calculate

```
825 miles / 200000 km
```

in a Google search box, and it yields about 0.006638 -- or about 6.6 msec.

Comment: You're dividing an imperial distance measurement, by a metric one... [200K KM == 124 274.238 miles](http://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&safe=active&client=firefox-a&hs=q5W&rls=org.mozilla%3Aen-US%3Aofficial&q=200000+km+to+miles&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=)

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Yes, and Google does the unit conversion for you.

Answer (score 2):

If there is [5.0 × 10<sup>-9</sup> s / m](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMG_enUS291US306&q=1+second+/+200,000+km&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) delay and if 825 miles are equivalent to [1,327,708.8 meters](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&rlz=1C1CHMG_enUS291US306&q=825+miles+to+meters&aq=f&aqi=h1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=) then the delay will be `(5*10^-9)*1327708.8` or **0.006638544 seconds**

Answer (score 1):

0.0066385440025356051588564794616356 seconds

Answer (score 1):

1 (sec) / 200,000 (KM) = 0.000005 (s / km)

1.609344 (mile in KM) x 825 = 1327.7088 KM

Therefore the delay over 825 miles is 0.006638544 seconds.